# recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while proxying and reading from upstream,

Tags: nginx, udp

I have a udp sender and a receiver, when i connect these two directly with a random port say 9999 in my local machine, they both exchange messages. Now i want sender to send to a nginx load balencer, and the nginx load balancer should forward the udp stream to receiver. Now at the sender end i am sending data to port 9999. while at the receiver, i am listening to port 5000. And hence my nginx.conf is as follows.

```
stream{
upstream dns_servers {
    least_conn;
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
    listen     9999 udp;
    #UDP traffic will be forwarded to the "dns_servers" upstream group
    proxy_pass dns_servers;
    proxy_responses 1;
}
}
```

my nginx is running inside a docker and hence my 'docker-compose' file is as follows

```
version: '3.4'

services:
   edsproxynginx:
    image: nginx
    extra_hosts:
       - "host.docker.internal:127.0.0.1"
```

And my 'docker-compose-override.yml' file is as follows

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  edsproxynginx:
    container_name: edsproxynginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./logs/:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./error/:/error/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9999:9999/udp"
```

Now i start the nginx container, post which i start the receiver after that i start the sender. Now in error.log i get the following errors

```
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49085 recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
proxying and reading from upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:1380/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49087 sendmsg() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while proxying and sending to upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:2760/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49089 recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
proxying and reading from upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:1380/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49091 sendmsg() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while proxying and sending to upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:2760/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49093 recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
proxying and reading from upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:1380/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49095 recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
proxying and reading from upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:1380/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49097 recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
proxying and reading from upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:1380/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
2022/07/03 04:51:17 [error] 31#31: *49099 recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
proxying and reading from upstream, udp client: 172.27.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:9999, 
upstream: "127.0.0.1:5000", bytes from/to client:1380/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/1380
```

Am i missing something?

**EDIT:**
OK here is the sender and receiver source code snippet written in c#

Sender side code

```
using var udpSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

var userExitSource = GetUserConsoleCancellationSource();

var cancelToken = userExitSource.Token;

const int PacketSize = 1380;

// Discard our socket when the user cancels.
using var cancelReg = cancelToken.Register(() => udpSocket.Dispose());

IPAddress.TryParse("127.0.0.1", out var destination);

var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(destination, 9999);

byte[] buffer = GC.AllocateArray<byte>(PacketSize, pinned: true);
Memory<byte> bufferMem = buffer.AsMemory();

// Put something approaching meaningful data in the buffer.
for (var idx = 0; idx < PacketSize; idx++)
{
    bufferMem.Span[idx] = (byte)idx;
}

Console.WriteLine("Ready to send");

while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    object value = await udpSocket.SendToAsync(bufferMem, SocketFlags.None, ipEndPoint, cancelToken);
    Console.WriteLine("Sent to " + ipEndPoint.Port.ToString());
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Ans receiver side code

```
public class Listner : BackgroundService
{
    private const int PacketSize = 1380;
    private static readonly IPEndPoint _blankEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++");
        using var udpSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        using var cancelReg = stoppingToken.Register(() => udpSocket.Dispose());
        udpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000));
     
        Console.WriteLine("Bind successful");
        await DoReceiveAsync(udpSocket, stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoReceiveAsync(Socket udpSocket, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        byte[] buffer = GC.AllocateArray<byte>(length: 65527, pinned: true);
        Memory<byte> bufferMem = buffer.AsMemory();

        while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await 
udpSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(bufferMem, SocketFlags.None, _blankEndpoint);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                // Socket exception means we are finished.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the receiver is a background service that runs as a Hosted Service in a Net 6 Web application.

Comment: You're missing the source code, for a start.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have updated the question with source code